# How to generate a 3-d matrix of coordindates numpy.meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate a matrix, say A, and the element of this matrix, say a_{ij}=(x_i,y_j) represents the coordinate of this point. I need the coordinate information to do further calculations. It seems if I could get this matrix, the following calculation should be more efficient than I use double loop (i:0:len(x_i), j:0:len(y_j)) to calculate each point.
The coordinate information is trivial:

```
num_xmesh = nx
num_ymesh = ny
x_start = xs
x_end = xe
y_start = ys
y_end = ye
x_grid=np.linspace(x_start,x_end,num_xmesh)
y_grid=np.linspace(y_start,y_end,num_ymesh)
```

I want to know how to generate this kind of matrix with numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stack the arrays returned by `np.meshgrid` using [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) to produce a 3D array with "spatial" coordinates in the first two dimensions and the coordinate values in the last dimension:

```
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]


a = np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing="ij"), axis=-1)

>>> print(a.shape)
(3, 3, 2)

>>> print(a)
[[[1 4]
  [1 5]
  [1 6]]

 [[2 4]
  [2 5]
  [2 6]]

 [[3 4]
  [3 5]
  [3 6]]]

>>> print(a[0, 0])
[1 4]  # a_00 = (x_0, y_0)

>>> print(a[0, 1])
[1 5]  # a_01 = (x_0, y_1)

>>> print(a[1, 0])
[2 4]  # a_10 = (x_1, y_0)
```

Comment: @yangyang Sure, just use the index `0` in the last dimension. For example, `a[..., 0]` for all of the x-coordinates, or `a[:, 0, 0]` for the x-coordinates of the first "column". I'm not sure what you mean by the second part re: your edit. If you want to recover `x` and `y` from `a`, you can use `x = a[:, 0, 0]` and `y = a[0, :, 1]`.

Comment: many thanks. I will try to get a better understanding of your method. It seems I need to use the separated x and y to calculate somefunction f(x,y) and afterwards I need to remap f(x,y) back to the matrix structure to do further calculation. So it there a way to do the remapping? In any case, your answer gives me a very good start to begin with. Good day!

Comment: @yangyang it sounds like you may be looking for [`numpy.apply_over_axes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html#numpy.apply_over_axes) or [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). It should be possible to avoid explicit for loops and/or manual construction in Python code. You could try posting a new question with details about the type of calculation you're trying to perform

Comment: what's your `f(x,y)`?  Can it only work with one scalar pair of `x,y` (per call)?  Or work with arrays?

Comment: @hpaulj I've wrote a code to solve f(x,y). It could work with arrays. I posted a new questions related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77511394/mapping-between-vectors-and-matrix

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the values of num_xmesh, num_ymesh, x_start, x_end, y_start, and y_end according to your specific requirements to generate the desired coordinate matrix A.

```
num_xmesh = 5  
num_ymesh = 4  
x_start = 0
x_end = 10
y_start = 0
y_end = 8

x_grid = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, num_xmesh)
y_grid = np.linspace(y_start, y_end, num_ymesh)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_grid, y_grid)

A = np.array([X.flatten(), Y.flatten()]).T

print("Matrix A (Coordinates):")
print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) or
[`np.mgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) to generate a single array that needs no stacking:

```
num_mesh = [nx, ny]
start = [xs, ys]
end = [xe, ye]
grid = (np.indices(num_mesh) * (end - start) + start).transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

OR

```
grid = (np.mgrid[:nx, :ny] * (end - start) + start).transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

The transpose is necessary if you want to have the coordinates in the last dimension rather than the first. It's not clear how you plan on using this grid, so it might not be necessary at all.

For that matter, you might be able to use broadcasting to avoid allocating the entire matrix to begin with. You might be able to index/reshape your original grid arrays, or equivalently use `indices(..., sparse=True)` or `ogrid` instead of `mgrid`.

The advantage of this approach is that it allocates a single array of coordinates once instead of first allocating the components and then copying them into the result buffer. That makes it more memory efficient and probably faster too. It won't matter for small examples in which it's not the bottleneck, but for large arrays you might notice a difference.