# mapping between vectors and matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I need to calculate values of some function based on the coordinates, say

```
f(x_i,y_i)
```

and the results should looks like a matrix:

```
f(x1,y1),f(x2,y1),...,f(xn,y1)
f(x1,y2),f(x2,y2),...,f(xn,y2)
..............................
f(x1,yn),f(x2,yn),...,f(xn,yn)
```

Now since the calculation of f(x,y) needs each x_i and y_i, I think the best way to do this is:

```
X=(x1,x2,x3,...,xn)
Y=(y1,y2,y3,...,yn)
```

And I could calculate f(x,y) without loops.
However, I need further calculations which requires the position of each f(xi,yi). To be specific, I need to calculate each determinant of a 2*2 sub-matrix:

```
d_{ij}=f(x_i,y_j)+f(x_{i+1},y_{j+1})-f(x_i,y_{j+1})-f(x_{i+1},y_j)
```

and store it in a new matrix. To my best knowledge, the way of solving the above mentioned problem are:

1. get X and Y
2. calculate f(X,Y)
3. remap f(X,Y) back to the matrix structure
4. calculate each determinant

I know how to do the first step:
[How to generate a 3-d matrix of coordindates numpy.meshgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77511182/how-to-generate-a-3-d-matrix-of-coordindates-numpy-meshgrid/77511211?noredirect=1#comment136647945_77511211)
The following is a minimum code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as scp
def GG(r):
    return np.sqrt((y-y0)**2 + r**2 * np.sin(r))
def beta1(r):
    return ((y-y0) - r * np.cos(r)) / GG(r)
def f(x,y):
    return scp.integrate.quad_vec(lambda r: 1/(np.sinh(self.beta1(r))))
x = np.linspace(2,5,10)
y = np.linspace(-5,5,10)
y0 = 1
x0 = 1
a = np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing="ij"), axis=-1)
xx = a[:, 0, 0]
yy = a[0, :, 1]
fxy = f(xx,yy)
```

Comment: How is `f` defined in Python?

Comment: @Brian61354270 it's a very complex function. But in general it could take X and Y as vectors. and the output is also a vector.

Comment: but then it calculates `f(x1,y1) f(x2,y2)... f(xn,yn)`, are you sure it calculates the whole matrix

Comment: @rioV8 I think if I could provide f(x,y) with a vector-form of X and Y, then f(x,y) could produce a vector. I am not sure about the matrix form since there is a numerical integration inside of f(x,y): scipy.integrate.quad_vec() which I am not sure only vector is allowed or matrix is also ok.

Answer (score 2):

As you already put up: to get X and Y values you can simply use np.meshgrid
For the second problem, using numpy you can calculate f(X,Y), depending on your logic you can simply put the @vectorize wrapper on the function and just call it with the X and Y that you have.
For the third part, this should be already done with step 2.
And finally, using a convolution would be one way to achieve what you are looking for on part 4.

If you are looking for a finite method approach, I would encourage you to look into numpy vectorize and their operations!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers showed various ways of getting an array that combines the 2 coordinate arrays into one.  But I'm not sure those help you understand the issues.

With `meshgrid` is can get a tuple of arrays that 'broadcast' against each other:

```
In [156]: x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5), np.arange(4),indexing='ij', sparse=True)

In [157]: x,y
Out[157]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]]),
 array([[0, 1, 2, 3]]))

In [158]: x.shape, y.shape
Out[158]: ((5, 1), (1, 4))
```

Without the `sparse` we get 2d arrays with (5,4) shape.  Functionally they are the same:

```
In [159]: X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5), np.arange(4),indexing='ij'); X.shape
Out[159]: (5, 4)
```

Both forms can be added (or multiplied, subtracted, etc), to produce as (5,4) result:

```
In [160]: x+y
Out[160]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])

In [161]: X+Y
Out[161]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

Doing things like `np.stack((X,Y),axis=-1)` produces a (5,4,2) array, but doesn't help with a function of the form `f(x,y)`.

`mgrid`, `ogrid`, `index` are other ways of getting the 2 arrays individually or combined.  Even `np.ix_`.

If your `f` doesn't handle broadcasting (as with `x,y` shape), but is ok with 2d arrays, you could give it `X,Y`.  If it only accepts 1d arrays, you could use

```
Z = f(X.ravel(), Y,ravel())
```

If `Z` is then the same shape as `X.ravel()`, you could reshape it to the same shape as `X`.

Comment: The f(x,y) is actually a vector (n_f,1) whose length is n_f=len(X)*len(Y) if X and Y are defined as above. All I need to do is map fxy back to the 2-d structure of matrix a(I add a small code above)